# How to run post condtion on the basis of git branch in JEnkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to send an email notificaiton with an attachment to code reviewers if the current branch being build is master  but if the branch is not master then I would like to send email to a developer who commited the code without an attachment.

```
if "${env.BRANCH_NAME}" == "master "{
    post {

        always {
            emailext(

        subject: "Build ${env.JOB_NAME} - ${currentBuild.displayName} ${currentBuild.result}",
        body: """Build ${currentBuild.result}
            ${env.JOB_URL}
            """,
        recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]
    )
        }
    } 
    }
    else {
        post {

        always {
            emailext(

        subject: "Build ${env.JOB_NAME} - ${currentBuild.displayName} ${currentBuild.result}",
        body: """Build ${currentBuild.result}
            ${env.JOB_URL}
            """,
        recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]
    )
        }
    }
```

I am getting  Not a valid section definition: "if ("${env.BRANCH_NAME}" == "master"){
    post { 
error in jenkins, Could anyone help me to get this done. 
Also Is there anyway to send email notifications to the code reviewers who merge the code to the branch from the github rather then the developers.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control)

Comment: I am getting the following error since I am trying to use if statement inside post instead of steps:Expected a step @ line 275, column 4.
      if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
      ^ and just wondering if there is a way to include if logic inside post which is after all stages.

Comment: I changed the code little bit from what it was in the link and it is working perfectly now.

Comment: Great to hear ! Please post new code as answer, it may help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the link provided by @arnaud claudel but it was still showing some errors but once I tweaked the code little bit as below then it is now working like a charm.

```
post { 
        always { 
            script {
                    if ("${env.BRANCH_NAME}" == 'master') {
                        emailext(
                         attachmentsPattern: "**/*_SC.sql",
                         subject: "Build ${env.JOB_NAME} - ${currentBuild.displayName} ${currentBuild.currentResult}",
                         body: """Build ${currentBuild.result}
                                    ${env.JOB_URL}
                               """,
                         to: 'admin@admin.com'
                     )
                    } else {
                        emailext(
                          subject: "Build ${env.JOB_NAME} - ${currentBuild.displayName} ${currentBuild.currentResult}",
                          body: """Build ${currentBuild.result}
                                     ${env.JOB_URL}
                                """,
                         recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
                         )
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

The trick was to add Script{} in the code so that the script inside that can be run for declarative post statement.

"${env.BRANCH_NAME}" can be replaced by env.BRANCH_NAME for linux system. My system was windows based so have to use ${env.BRANCH_NAME} as an env variable to get the name of the branch.